# Chrome version 57 broke my SVG transforms

Tags: google-chrome, svg

To update the position of a SVG group of elements (lines,circles etc) I use a call like this:

```
$('#g-srcDocView_container').attr('transform', 'translate(0,0) scale(0.301)');
```

I have created a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/tcnjay11/

The line should be in the yellow area, but when my javascript call runs to slightly modify the transform (scale or translation doesn't matter), the position jumps out in the bushes.

It works in IE, Firefox, Safari and Chrome <=56.
It doesn't work in Stable,Beta or Dev versions of Chrome.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome 57+, `transform-origin` is now a valid presentation attribute.  Previously it had no effect, but now it does. In Firefox it is still ignored unless it is set in CSS.

The quick fix is to remove the `transform-origin` attribute from that element.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=709821

Comment: Thanks, that was quick :) I

Comment: This issue just broke my graph! And you solved it! Thanks a lot!